# Nginx: Set up sub-sub-domains

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I rent a V-Server and I got a sub-domain like abc.provider.net. On my server, I set up a set of docker containers using docker-compose providing web apps. Now I want to set up Nginx in order to access them. (Later I want to set up certbot for SSL.)

When setting Nginx

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;

    server_name abc.provider.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://172.15.12.03:11132;
        proxy_buffering    off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

I can reach the app. But I can't set up more.

So I thought to create sub-sub-domains:

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;

    server_name app1.abc.provider.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://172.15.12.03:11132;
        proxy_buffering    off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

But this leads me to:

```
This site can’t be reached
app1.abc.provider.net refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

How to set up Nginx correctly? Or is this approach not feasible?

Comment: Did you set up corresponding DNS records for the subdomain?

Comment: Where can I do that? - Btw. I rent a domain now, so this is no longer a problem.
But anyhow, I'm interested in a solution. Who knows what's coming next.

Comment: It depends on your registrar how you set up domain name <-> IP address mappings. So, I can only tell that you need to add an entry to DNS that maps the subdomain to the IP address of the server.